# Zebra printer prints random characters for numbers in ZPL

Tags: php, zebra-printers, zpl

I was testing some ZPL code and printing them via my zebra printer GK420d

```
$leftdistance=100;
$topdistance=300;
$labeltext='100x300';
$ZplCode='^XA^FO'.$leftdistance.','.$topdistance.'^FD '.$labeltext.'^FS^XZ';
$fp = fsockopen("xxx.xxx.x.xx", xxxx, $errno, $errstr);
        fwrite($fp, $ZplCode, strlen($ZplCode));
    fclose($fp);
```

it returns this string but on the label, it is printing gibberish

```
^XA^FO100,300^FD100x300^FS^XZ
```

this line is supposed to print `100x300` but it is printing gibberish characters like  ‎`€//xΦ//` for `100x300` any idea what I have done wrong.

Comment: Where's your code? Without seeing that, we have no idea what you're doing

Comment: Works fine [here](http://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=6&quality=grayscale&width=3&height=2&units=inches&index=0&zpl=%5EXA%0AFO100%2C300%5EFD100x300%5EFS%0ACF1%2C15%5EFO100%2C270%5EFD36977%5EFS%0A%5EXZ) so it must be a settings issue with your printer or this isn't actually the ZPL you are running.

Comment: @DelphiCoder I have updated the question

Comment: Have you inspected the data (e.g. with wireshark) you send to the printer? Is it plain ``ASCII`` or something else (``UTF8``, ``Unicode``)? If it is not plain ``ASCII``, give the function [``mb_convert_encoding``](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) a try...